# What is th tap100i0 device on my debian with KVM?

Tags: networking, configuration, kvm-virtualization, tap

I want configure a network for virtual machines on KVM. I created a bridge. But I found a new tap100i0 devise was created. Should I take it into account to get the virtual network running?

Answer (score 0):

it is an interface for connected VM